# How to solve the issue with "to display the website again, the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted"

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer

I have a parent page asp.net and in a popup windows I have this:

```
<body onunload="parent.opener.location.reload()">
    <form id="silverlightWindows" runat="server" />
</body>
```

The problem is that when the popup windows is closed, it always asks this confirmation information with IE and Firefox:

```
to display the website again, the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted
```

How can I remove the message warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is showing because you are trying to reload the location of the parent window, and that window is currently displaying the result of a post back.

To fix it you will either have to:

- Only open the popup after a "normal" non-post back request.

or

- Not use use `location.reload()` but instead use `location='(url to load here)'`. This could work if the state of the parent window can be restored without the post back data.

or

- You could use javascript to cause a postback on the parent window.

Comment: I am very appreciated about your solutions. COuld you please give me sample answers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a way to avoid this issue on ie?

Answer (score 3):

After the user has successfully submitted a form you should redirect the user. This is called the [Post/Redirect/Get "pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: I want to re direct the parent location after the user has closed the windows popup. Therefore, I used onunload. Is there any different way to tackle it with Redirect method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to *redirect* them, why are you calling *reload*?

Comment: that is the only possible way that I came up with to reload the parent page after the windows is closed. do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: It's isn't the fact that a popup closes which causes the message in user agents, but rather a form which has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of "Internet Explorer need to resend the information you've previously submitted"
use this script block

```
>    window.parent.opener.document.forms[0].submit() ;
```

Comment: error: "Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference"